# Как корректно переустановить Git Bash?

Tags: git, git-bash

Осенью изучал основы Ruby и RoR по серии видеоуроков, и там при изучении Git особо не акцентировали внимание, куда устанавливать клиент Git Bash. Просто говорили, что в C:\Program Files лучше этого не делать из-за пробела в названии папки. В итоге все закончилось установкой в C:\RailsInstaller\Git

Сейчас перешел к андроиду, и столкнулся со всем этим заново. Не логично размещать гит-клиент в папке RailsInstaller, который сейчас просто занимает место на диске.

Как корректнее будет поступить?

Анинсталлировать старый Git Bash и поставить новый в нейтральную папку, не привязанную ни к чему конкретно, например, C:\Git? Где при этом останутся старые настройки гит-клиента? Надо ли будет их подчищать, лезть ли в реестр, переменные среды?

ОС: **Win7x64bit**

Answer (score 3):

Система настроек **Git** включает три уровня:

1. Системный: для всех пользователей системы.
2. Глобальный: настройки конкретного пользователя.
3. Локальный: настройки для конкретного репозитория.

Каждый более конкретный уровень настроек перекрывает настройки более общего, то есть настройки для пользователя переопределяют настройки в системном файле конфигурации **Git**. Наибольшим приоритетом обладают настройки для текущего репозитория, с которым Вы работаете.

Файл системных настроек в Windows - это `etc\gitconfig` относительно корня mingw64, который находится в каталоге, куда установлен **Git**

Файл настроек пользователя: `C:\Users\$USER\.gitconfig`

Файл настроек репозитория: `.git\gitconfig`, в каталоге, используемого репозитория

Для просмотра и установки параметров Git есть команда `git config`. Для этой команды есть три параметра, определяющие уровень настроек:

- `--system` - системный, для всех пользователей
- `--global` - глобальный, для текущего пользователя
- `--local` - локальный, для используемого репозитория

Более подробно о настройках **Git** посмотрите в документации:

[Первоначальная настройка Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)

[Настройка Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-Git-Configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Сколько лет уже нет с нами MS-DOS, в которой папки с пробелами в имени вызывали проблемы - а страх до сих пор остался.

Не бойтесь, ставьте в C:\Program files - всё будет нормально.

А папку гит я лично использую под проекты, например:

C:\git\github.com\EduardoPires\EquinoxProject\ - https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject.git

В этой папке находятся в формате сервер\пользователь\проект отдельные репозитории

Ну или если вы так суеверны, то создайте себе папку C:\Prog\Git - я видел подобных коллег, кто до сих пор не любит папку Program files и создаёт Prog